# Jquery Change Links with Images

Tags: jquery, url, replace

I have this code for example:

```
<table class="catsTable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid5" valign="top">
        <a href="/load/prison_break_online/sezonul_1/5" >Sezonul 1</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[6]</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid6" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_2/6" class="catName">Sezonul 2</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid7" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_3/7" class="catName">Sezonul 3</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid8" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_4/8" class="catName">Sezonul 4</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

And i want to change this:

```
 <a href="/load/prison_break_online/sezonul_1/5" >Sezonul 1</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[6]</span>
```

Into something like :

```
<img src="/images/pris5.png"> <br> 
     <a href="/load/prison_break_online/sezonul_1/5" >Sezonul 1</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[6]</span>
```

`pris5.png` == first 4 letters from series prison_break_online (pris) and the id of series
sezonul_1/5(5) .. I get ID by next formula =>.. if last 2 characters from url <10 => get last charcter from url else get last 2 characters from url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are going to be a few ways to do it, but [here is one](http://jsfiddle.net/MhQw3/)

A simple jQuery function grabs each `TD` by class name and then parses the `href` attribute.

```
$(function(){
   $(".catsTd").each(function( index ) {
       var tmp1 = $(this).children("a").attr('href').split('/');
       $(this).prepend("<img src='/images/" + tmp1[1].substring(0, 4) + tmp1[3] + ".png'> <br>")      
    }); 
});
```

Your original HTML reformatted:

```
<table class="catsTable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid5" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_1/5" class="catName">Sezonul 1</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid6" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_2/6" class="catName">Sezonul 2</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid7" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_3/7" class="catName">Sezonul 3</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid8" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_4/8" class="catName">Sezonul 4</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: txn .. looks like works on your example but here: http://www.ufilme.ro/load?lista_seriale_online?t1 all images are : "/seriale/images/gr2/load.png"

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the array created when splitting on the '/'.  Your example is completely different than your actual code.  You will need to use a different index when you create the image string.  I don't know what image you are trying to point to, but try something like this : `$(this).prepend("<img src='/images/" + tmp1[4].substring(0, 4) + tmp1[5] + ".png'> <br>");`